# How to calculate the difference between two geometry_msgs::Pose

Tags: ros-kinetic, quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two geometry_msgs::Pose structure p1 and p2. Each of them contains a geometry_msgs::Point and geometry_msgs::Quaternion. I would like to calculate the different between the two poses. I know the difference in position is just the subtraction. But I am not sure how to calculate the difference in orientation. I know for tf::quaternion, I can use inverse, but the function "inverse" does not seem available for geometry_msgs::quaternion.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310383/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-geometry_msgs::pose/) by [AutoCar](https://answers.ros.org/users/35903/autocar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 102 on 2018-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the tutorial on calculating a [relative rotation](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Quaternions#Relative_rotations) between quaternions. After you have the difference as a quaternion, you can [convert it](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Quaternions#Think_in_RPY_then_convert_to_quaternion) to roll/pitch/yaw. For Python, use quaternion_to_euler() for that. Finally, it's no problem to convert between tf and geometry_msg quaternions. The tutorial also has some examples of that.

Please add to the tutorial if it's not explicit enough. For example, I see that it shows how to convert tf->geometry_msgs but not the other way around.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2018-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4